# Passing a directive a promise as an attirbute value to be used for ng-options creates infinite digest loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two directives in my code where parent directive's template contains child directive. The child directive is passed an attribute called "items" and it calls a function which will be returning a promise.

The child directive's controller then takes that items promise and does a 'then' to get the results. These results are then to be displayed in the dropdown.

I have been working with this code for a while now and am not able to figure out the warning I am getting. Also, I am not getting the right results.

Basically, when you click on Change Value button, it will return a different array. Odd numbers and event numbers provide different arrays (this was so I could simulate change to the model).

Below is the code and here is a link to the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/aliasgerj/pen/yoYLgY)

*Parent Controller*

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope, $q) {
  var that = this;
  that.r = 0;
  var i = [{ name: "toronto" }, { name: "chicago" }, { name: "new york" }];

  var j = [{ name: "Martin" }, { name: "Stephanie" }, { name: "Kirk" }];

  this.getItems = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (that.r % 2 == 0) {
      console.log("getItems: i returned");
      deferred.resolve(i);
    } else {
      console.log("getItems: j returned");
      deferred.resolve(j);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  this.changeVal = function() {
    that.r += 1;
    console.log(that.r);
  };
});
```

*Parent Directive*

```
app.directive("parentDirective", function() {
  return {
    template:
    '<child-directive items="ct.getItems()"></child-directive><button ng-click="ct.changeVal()">Change Value</button>',
    controller: "mainCtrl",
    controllerAs: "ct",
    scope: {}
  };
});
```

*Child Controller*

```
app.controller("childCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Child controller";
  $scope.returnedItems =[];
  $scope.items.then(function(result){
    console.log("Child controller THEN from promise executed");
    $scope.returnedItems = result;
  });
});
```

*Child Directive*

```
app.directive("childDirective", function() {
  return {
    template:
    '<select ng-model="selectedAction" ng-options="x.name for x in returnedItems"><option value="">Select</option></select>',
    controller: "childCtrl",
    scope: {
      items: "<"
    }
  };
});
```

when I run the code above, I do get the drop-down populated. But it doesn't change after.

Appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the part in your child directive here,

```
items="ct.getItems()"
```

You are giving the child directive's scope the *result* of that function. In this case, a promise. When this promise gets resolved your child scope sets the ng-options to the result as expected. However subsequent calls to `ct.getItems()` creates a *new* promise that your child directive knows nothing about.

In my opinion, the cleanest way to get your results into the child is to pass the items array into the child directive. And whenever `getItems()` is called from the parent directive, update the results array. It simplifies a lot of the code. Here's your modified code. The main thing to note is that the child directive binds to currentItems array instead of the promise, and the array is updated whenever `getItems()` is called.

```
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope, $q) {
  var that = this;
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  that.r = 0;
  var i = [{ name: "toronto" }, { name: "chicago" }, { name: "new york" }];

  var j = [{ name: "Martin" }, { name: "Stephanie" }, { name: "Kirk" }];
  that.currentItems = i;
  this.getItems = function () {

    if (that.r % 2 == 0) {
      console.log("getItems: i returned");
      that.currentItems = i;
      deferred.resolve(i);
    } else {
      console.log("getItems: j returned");
      that.currentItems = j;
      deferred.resolve(j);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  this.changeVal = function() {
    that.r += 1;
    this.getItems();
    console.log(that.r);
  };
});

app.directive("parentDirective", function() {
  return {
    template:
    '<child-directive items="ct.currentItems"></child-directive><button ng-click="ct.changeVal()">Change Value</button>',
    controller: "mainCtrl",
    controllerAs: "ct",
    scope: {}
  };
});

app.controller("childCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Child controller";
});

app.directive("childDirective", function() {
  return {
    template:
    '<select ng-model="selectedAction" ng-options="x.name for x in items"><option value="">Select</option></select>',
    controller: "childCtrl",
    scope: {
      items: "<"
    }
  };
});
```

[Heres a plunker using your example](https://plnkr.co/edit/UuXFOZO4eYGjzA7WJllx)